# No instance of constructor "Hourly::Hourly" matches argument list and Error code C2664 on the same line

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am quite lost on how to solve my question. I have read many posts and it's just not clicking on how they apply to my problem and as I look over my code I can't seem to see what is broken.

```
Main:
Hourly hourly("John", "Smith", "12345", 123456789, 42.0, 45.5); //error's occur on john and
```

I'll add the hourly class as well

```
Hourly.cpp:
#include "Hourly.h"

Hourly::Hourly() : Employee()
{
    hours = 0;
    rate = 0;
}

Hourly::Hourly(string fName, string lName, string ssn, string phone, float hours, float rate):Employee(fName,lName,ssn,phone)
{
    this->hours = hours;
    this->rate = rate;
}

Hourly::~Hourly(void)
{
}

// Behaviors
string Hourly::toString()
{
    string hourlyString = Employee::toString();
    hourlyString = hourlyString + "Hours: " + to_string(hours) + "Rate: " + to_string(rate);
    return hourlyString;
}

float Hourly::calculatePay()
{
    if (hours > 40)
    {
        return((40 * rate) + ((hours - 40)*rate*1.5));
    }
    else
        return(hours * 40);
}

// Accessors and Mutators
float Hourly::gethours(void)
{
    return hours;
}

void Hourly::sethours(float hours)
{
    this->hours = hours;
}

float Hourly::getrate(void)
{
    return rate;
}

void Hourly::setrate(float rate)
{
    this->rate = rate;
}
```

My question is why isn't my code working? I have 2 errors on the line in the main
1. No instance of constructor "Hourly::Hourly" matches argument list
2. Error code C2664 cannot convert argument 4 from 'int' to 'std::string'

I am new to C++ and getting frustrated trying to debug my code so I now I am just overlooking something simple here. Any comments or answers are appreciated I'm just trying to learn. Cheers!

Comment: The error messages seem pretty self-explanatory to me. The phone number is a string, and you're passing an int. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be the phone number, which you're passing to the constructor as:

```
123456789
```

Your constructor expects a string, but without quotes, this is an integer.

Pass it as follows and you shouldn't have an issue:

```
"123456789"
```

Comment: Yep, it's working I knew it was something so simple. I'll mark your answer when Stack lets me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `phone` argument is supposed to be a `string` but you're giving it an integer; wrap argument 4 in quotes.

I should note that the error said exactly this, that you're trying to put an int where a string belongs. Make sure to read your errors carefully, they're usually very helpful!